# Allowed row operations on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Can I get this matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}

from the identity matrix $I_3$ like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

Add second row to first row. Then subtract second row from itself. Is the subtraction of a row from itself allowed?

Comment: you can't, because allowed operations let rank invariant. Here, the first matric has rank 2 and the second one has rank 3.

Comment: Whether a matrix operation is "allowed" depends on what you need the matrix for. If you need to describe a linear map on a given basis/bases, then only one precise matrix will do, and no operations at all are allowed. If you are using matrices to represent systems of equations, then row operations (not including subtraction from itself) are allowed, but column operations are not. Other cases yet, other rules.

Comment: I suggest that you check out David Butler's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863575/can-you-use-row-and-column-operations-interchangeably/863727#863727).

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot subtract a row from itself!

Besides, your first matrix is *not* invertible, whereas the identity matrix is.

Valid row operations on a singular matrix (non-invertible) will *never* yield a non-singular (invertible) matrix, while valid row operations on an invertible matrix will always yield another invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not subtract a row from its self.

Please see this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations).

The matrix you want to obtain is a rank 2 matrix where as $I_3$ is a rank 3 matrix.
In other words as amWhy suggested you can not get a non invertible matrix from an invertible matrix through valid [elementary row operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations).

Answer (score 0):

No, because row operations on a matrix $A$ preserve the solutions of $Ax=0$.

For the first matrix, the system is $x_1+x_2=0$, $x_3=0$, which has general solution $(t,-t,0)$.

For the second matrix (the identity matrix), the general solution is $(0,0,0)$.